# defining functions on __proto__ while hiding from console.log

Tags: javascript

Can I define functions on proto? Part of the objective is to have getter and setters but not creating any noise when I `console.log` the object. I've noticed anything defined on prototype is not included in the `console.log`.

```
function ValueObject() {
    var authentication; //private variable

    __proto__.getAuthentication = function() {return authentication};
    __proto__.setAuthentication = function(val) {authentication = val};

    this.val = val;
}
```

Desired behavior.

```
var vo1 = new ValueObject(1);
console.log(vo1); // ValueObject { val: 1 } (desired behavior)
```

My objective is to show value only in `console.log` while hiding all those getters and setters from user of the library because they are of internal nature and use.

The problem is getter and setters are not accessible when i instantiate the object.

Comment: No, that is impossible - the prototype is shared by all your instances so you cannot put privileged instance-specific methods on it. Solve your actual problem and define a `toString` or `inspect` method that reduces noise for logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The private variable needs to be publicly exposed in order to access it from the prototype chain. If you need the variable to be private, you will have to deal with seeing the public functions in the console.

Comment: error `ValueObject.prototype.getAuthentication = function() {return authentication};` and description of error is `ReferenceError: authentication is not defined`

Comment: You'll need to make authentication public and use this.authentication

Comment: authentication is private and can't be exposed

Comment: Okay, then it needs to go into an IIFE. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: there's a problem, the variable authentication is static and common across all instances. `var vo1 = new ValueObject(1);
vo1.setAuthentication("a");
var vo2 = new ValueObject(2);
vo2.setAuthentication("b");` it displays `b` two times

Comment: Right.. yeah.. that makes sense, since it's in the prototype. I was trying a weird combination of things to meet your needs but didn't think it through.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116742/discussion-between-t-b-and-user2727195).

Comment: Is there a solution with adding a super class, put getters and setters there? so console.log doesn't show everything up in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

```
function ValueObject(val) {

    private_val = val; //private

    ValueObject.prototype.get =()=> {
        this.authentication = private_val;

        return this.authentication; // public now
    }
}
var auth = new ValueObject('test');
alert('private: '+auth.private_val); // can't receive, it's private hence undefined
alert('private: '+auth.authentication); // neither
alert('public: '+auth.get()); // here you can
```

IMHO, that's the basic principal. should be working - and `()=>` is short for `function()`.

**EDIT:** and here for a set/get construct example... this should work too:

```
function ValueObject() {

    var private_val; //private

    ValueObject.prototype.set =(val)=> {
        private_val = val; // private variable gets a value 
    }

    ValueObject.prototype.get =()=> {
        this.authentication = private_val; // public variable gets the private value 

        return this.authentication; // public now
    }
}
var auth = new ValueObject;
auth.set('test');
alert('private: '+auth.private_val); // can't receive, it's private hence undefined
alert('private: '+auth.authentication); // neither
alert('public: '+auth.get()); // here you can
```

[check demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/hpghp83h/)

Comment: What does `=()=>` mean?

Comment: short for `function()` .. sorry I'm used to type that I'll put in function() as info

Comment: @CayeAuriga is private_val has a same value for two different objects? I think that's what the issue we ran into from the other answer, see my comments there. crate auth1 = new ValueObject, and auth2 = new ValueObject and see if they have different auth values, that's what the point is

Comment: For the set/get version of course they do. If you create multiple instances and set a differen't value for each [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/p4c0ezxm/)